# Is there a way to get "Bettter" Skype?

Tags: skype

I am new to linux and I am a previous windows user. I dont like the Skype 4.x layout/look. Is there a way I can use a newer version of Skype without using a VM?

I have already tried using VM's. They work flawlessly, but are too resource intensive just to run skype.

Comment: Skype 4 is latest Skype for Linux. The numbering has nothing to do with Skype for Windows.

Comment: do your research before you comment. because it is incorect.

Comment: Skype 4.3 is latest Skype for Linux

Comment: yes, but it has everything to do with the version standpoint of windows

Answer (score 0):

If it helps, Try installing Skype Windows application on your system using Wine

```
sudo apt-get install wine
```

After Wine is installed, you can install  Skype on it.

Answer (score 0):

Doing this from my phone but you could try hangouts.  It works as a chrome app on your desktop and works exactly like Skype.  I also heard Skype is coming in the form of a web app soon.  I'll post the links when I get back to my desktop.